# removing excess spaces from a string (and counting them)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to remove all excess whitespace characters from a string, so that there are no more than 1 in a row. I also need to print a line which contains the largest consecutive number of whitespace characters removed.

this is what i have so far, but all it does right now is return the string back to me.

```
def spaceremover(text):
    for i in range(1,len(text)):
        if i==' ':
            if text[i-1]==' ':
                del i


def spacecounter(text):
    count=0
    maxcount=0
    for i in range(1,len(text)):
        if i==' ':
            if text[i-1]==' ':
                count=count+1
        elif count>maxcount:
           maxcount=count
            count=0
        else: 
            count=0
    return maxcount


def main(text):
    spacecounter(text)
    spaceremover(text)
    text=''.join(text)
    print (text)

text=list(input())
main(text)
```

Comment: You can start by adding  print(spacecounter(text)) inside main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would regex this, but since that has already been suggested, here's a more DIY approach (just for completeness):

```
def countSpaces(s):
    answer = []
    start = None
    maxCount = 0
    for i,char in enumerate(s):
        if char == ' ':
            if start is None:
                start = i
                answer.append(char)
        else:
            if start is not None:
                maxCount = max(i-start-1, maxCount)
                start = None
            answer.append(char)
    print("The whitespace normalized string is", ''.join(answer))
    print("The maximum length of consecutive whitespace is", maxCount)
```

Output:

```
>>> s = "foo    bar  baz                        bam"
>>> countSpaces(s)
The whitespace normalized string is foo bar baz bam
The maximum length of consecutive whitespace is 23
```

Comment: the counting part works fine, but im having trouble with the removing part. It seems to remove most of the string except for the first letters of words. i.e                           countSpaces('good    bye    doggy')
The whitespace normalized string is  b d

Comment: @user2782067: check it out now

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo    bar  baz                        bam"
>>> len(max(re.findall(" +", s), key=len))
24
>>> re.sub(" {2,}", " ", s)
'foo bar baz bam'
```